In this code why am I getting an '@' character before the first letter?
This is a code for copying a string to another string.
  char A[100], B[100];
  printf("\nInput a string:\n");
  fgets(A,100,stdin);
  int i=0;
  while(B[i] = A[i++]);
  printf("\nString copied in the new array is:\n%s",B);
  return 0;
 

OUTPUT (This is the output I received)
Input a string:
i don't knoww??
String copied in the new array is:
@i don't knoww??
I was expecting the output: (without '@' at the start)
Input a string:
i don't knoww??
String copied in the new array is:
i don't knoww??

You have undefined behaviour — you cannot use both B[i] and A[i++] in the assignment; you don't know when the increment is performed.  Fix: use for (int i = 0; (B[i] = A[i]) != '\0'; i++) ; (with the empty loop body on a separate line).  You're allowed to omit the inner parentheses and the != '\0' condition, though that's what is being tested whether you write it out or not.

Use a for loop instead: for (size_t i = 0; B[i] = A[i]; ++i);

I think this is the 3rd time today that some flavour of the i = i++ question was asked...
